# Open Windows SDK command prompt in Windows 10

Tags: maven, hadoop, sdk, installation, windows-10

I have Installed Windows SDK on windows 10 from here

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

But I am unable to open Windows SDK command prompt to run my maven commands to install hadoop. I have searched online but didn't find anything useful. Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Windows 7.1 SDK was really the last one to include it's own "Command Prompt". For Windows 8.x and Windows 10 SDK, you usually install Visual Studio to get the Windows SDK which provides the "Developer Command Prompt" shortcut.

Keep in mind that the Windows 10 SDK uses a "side-by-side" model so `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include` or `Lib\<arch>` is not sufficient to point to the include/lib path. You need to add a version string. For example, for the November 2015 update, it would be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10586.0` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10586.0\um\<arch>`

In the Visual Studio 2015 Developer Command Prompt, you will see the following environment variables:

```
WindowsSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\

WindowsSDKLibVersion=10.0.10586.0\

WindowsSDKVersion=10.0.10586.0\

INCLUDE=...C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kit s\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\shared;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\winrt;

LIB=...C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10586.0\ucrt\x64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10586.0\um\x64;

LIBPATH=...C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer sir. Your help is really appreciated. Because in every tutorial I saw they say Windows SDK Command Prompt but I was unable to find it. Thanks alot. :)